# New To Orbeon Forms and Need Mysql Connection With Orbeon CE

Tags: orbeon

I have Few Doubts about Orbeon CE

1. If i build the form in form builder how this form can be used in my other context of webapps(I am Using Tomcat 6).

   ```
   for ex: categoryfrom i build in orbeon context. I want to use this form in My own Context example foo.
   ```
2. How can i proceed with database connection in Orbeon CE to save the data that are entered in the form i build in orbeon. If i click on database connection it is saying like "This Feature is supported in PE version only".

3.How to Establish the Database(Mysql) connection with the form build in Orbeon CE. I have gone through your site but Its not in detail with Orbeon CE.

1. Orbeon CE says that Mysql is supported. In What way?

Answer (score 0):

- About the **location of deployed forms**: forms you create with Form Builder are also ran by Orbeon Forms. After you hit the *Publish* button in Form Builder, the form becomes available on a path that depends on the app and form name you chose when creating the form. For instance, if you have Orbeon Forms deployed on `http://www.example.com/orbeon`, and your app is called `patients` and the form is called `registration`, the URL to fill out a new form will be:

  `http://www.example.com/orbeon/fr/patients/regisration/new`
- To **setup Orbeon Forms with MySQL**, see [Oracle and MySQL Persistence Layers](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/form-runner/oracle-and-mysql-persistence-layers). You don't need to use *Services and Actions* for this. The latter is not for form data persistence, but to make queries to the database, say to populate a drop-down, or pre-populate a field live based on a value entered in another field.